# How to create a network policy for only one schema

Tags: snowflake-schema

I want to create a policy to give access to the CALENDAR schema from two different servers, is that possible?
Please need help.
I tried this below link but it doesnt show schema level policy.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-network-policy.html
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Network policies can only be set at the account or user level [Network Policies](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/network-policies.html#network-policies)

To respond to your comment: the policy cannot be applied to the particular schema level

Comment: Thanks NickW, so the policy cannot be applied to the particular schema level?